# How to melt a DataTable in C# .NET (wide to long format)?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

How to melt a `DataTable` in C# (wide to long format) as Python `Pandas.melt` does? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

Is there any method already implemented? If not, how the code for melting a `DataTable` would

For example:

[image]

I have one DataTable which is in wide format, that is that has one row per id and has as many columns as variables. I would like to transform this DataTable to long format that has as many rows as combinations of id with each variable column. You can see this example in top image.

Please, if there is not clear enough visit Pandas documentation, there is more clear. (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

Note: I would like a solution that is DataTable independent, that is, that the solution is able to take parameters as `id_vars`, `value_vars`, etc... like `Pandas.melt` does

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that `Melt` method but according to [docs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-melt/) it seems to be an unpivot method:

```
public static DataTable MeltTable(DataTable inputTable, string outputColumn, params string[] unpivotColumns)
{
    DataTable resultTable = new DataTable();
    DataColumn col = new DataColumn(outputColumn, inputTable.Columns[outputColumn].DataType);
    resultTable.Columns.Add(col);
    resultTable.Columns.Add("Variable");
    resultTable.Columns.Add("Value");
    foreach(string unpivotColumn in unpivotColumns)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in inputTable.Rows)
        {
            resultTable.Rows.Add(row[outputColumn], unpivotColumn, row[unpivotColumn]);
        }
    }
    
    return resultTable;
}
```

You use it in this way:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Name");
table.Columns.Add("Course");
table.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
table.Rows.Add("Tim", "Masters", 47);
table.Rows.Add("Bob", "Graduate", 19);
table.Rows.Add("Sheila", "Graduate", 20);
DataTable resultTable = MeltTable(table, "Name", "Course", "Age");
```

Result:

```
Name    Variable     Value
Tim     Course       Masters
Bob     Course       Graduate 
Sheila  Course       Graduate 
Tim     Age          47 
Bob     Age          19 
Sheila  Age          20
```

Answer (score 0):

@TimSchmelter gave me the answer but I modified a little bit to be a more general solution. Here's the code:

```
    public static List<string> GetDifferenceColumns(DataTable dt, List<string> diffCols)
    {
        string[] columns = GetColumnsList(dt).ToArray();
        IEnumerable<string> differenceColumns = from column in columns.Except(diffCols.ToArray()) select column;
        return differenceColumns.ToList();


    }

    public static DataTable Melt(DataTable dt, List<string> idCols = null, List<string> varCols = null)
    {
        string errorPrefixString = "Error in DataProcessing Melt Method:\n";
        bool varsColsIsNull = (varCols == null || varCols.Count == 0);
        bool idColsIsNull = (idCols == null || idCols.Count == 0);
        string varsName = "Variable";
        string valueName = "Value";
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception(errorPrefixString + "DataTable is empty");
        }
        if (varsColsIsNull && varsColsIsNull)
        {
            throw new Exception(errorPrefixString+"You should past at least varCols or idCols");
        }
        if (varsColsIsNull)
        {
            varCols = GetDifferenceColumns(dt, idCols);
        }
        if (idColsIsNull)
        {
            idCols = GetDifferenceColumns(dt, varCols);
        }

        DataTable resultTable = new DataTable();
        // Creating final columns of resultTable
        foreach (string id in idCols)
        {
            resultTable.Columns.Add(id);
        }
        resultTable.Columns.Add(varsName);
        resultTable.Columns.Add(valueName);
        
        // Populating resultTable with the new rows
        // generated by unpivoting varCols
        foreach (string varCol in varCols)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                DataRow resultRow = resultTable.NewRow();
                foreach(string id in idCols)
                {
                    resultRow[id] = row[id]; // create id cols
                }
                resultRow[varsName] = varCol;
                resultRow[valueName] = row[varCol];
                resultTable.Rows.Add(resultRow);

            }
        }
        return resultTable;
    }
```

#### How to use it:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("Course");
    dt.Columns.Add("Age");
    dt.Rows.Add("Tim", "Masters", 47);
    dt.Rows.Add("Bob", "Graduate", 19);
    dt.Rows.Add("Sheila", "Graduate", 20);
    List<string> varCols = new List<string> { "Course", "Age" };
    DataTable finalDataTable = Melt(dt, varCols: varCols);
```

Comment: Same scenario, but I need some other output columns like name ,rollno , college as it is. Can you please help me how to achieve that

Comment: I don't understand, could you elaborate?